# How can i clone translated fields using Sonata and Knp Translatable Behavior

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin, sonata

Please, how can i clone an object with its translatable fields content using Sf3 + SonataAdminBundle and Knp Trabnslatable behavior as translations strategy.

I already created a custom action to clone my object, all non-translatable fields are cloned and inserted correctly except those that are translatable.

```
//Custom action to clone the object
public function  cloneAction($id){

    $object = $this->admin->getSubject();

    if( !$object && !is_object( $object ))
    {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException( 'Enable to find the object with the id : '. $id );
    }

    $clonedObject = clone $object;

    $ret = $this->admin->create( $clonedObject );
    $clonedObject->translate()->setTitle( $object->translate()->getTitle(). ' (Cloned)' );

    $this->addFlash( 'sonata_flash_success', 'Cloned successfully' );

    return new RedirectResponse( $this->admin->generateUrl('list') );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In php, when you clone an object, references are not cloned. That's called shallow copy. All you need to do is also clone the translation objects.

```
<?php
foreach ($clonedObject->getTranslations() as $translation) {
    $clonedObject->removeTranslation($translation);
    $clonedObject->addTranslation(clone $translation);
}
```

Comment: Thank you greg0ire, i appreciate your help and your quick reply.
Just one more problem, when I clone the object, the new cloned one is good, but the parent one loses his translations (translations removed !)...Do you have any idea about that, thanks.

Comment: I found the problem here is what i changed in the code :

`foreach ($clonedObject->getTranslations() as $translation) {
            //$clonedObject->removeTranslation($translation);
            $translation->setTitle( $translation->getTitle().' (Cloned) ' );
            $clonedObject->addTranslation(clone $translation);
        }`